# why child component getting instantiated more num of times than needed when used by 2 different components?

Tags: dynamic, angular, components, loader

I am trying to instantiate child component on click of a button in parent component. This same child component need to get instantiated on click of 2 more buttons in a different component. This child component is nothing but a modal component and basically modal component needs to get instantiated from 2 different components(one in header, another in parent). I have a modal template in which modal data comes dynamically. I am instantiating modal component using dynamic component loader. Now modal component is getting instantiated when buttons are clicked. But they are instantiated more times than expected.
Below is header html where click of one button is happening:

```
  <-- code here-->
 <!-- FAQModal -->
 <modal-component #modalID></modal-component> // modal-component is selector of modal.html
  <-- code here-->
<li [style.display]="!showFAQ?'none':'inherit'"><a (click)="getFAQ()" data-remote="false"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTarget"><i class="fa fa-question"></i>FAQ</a></li>
```

**header.component.ts** -

```
getFAQ() {
    this._modalService.setModalId('FAQ');
    if (this.component !== undefined) {
        this.component.then((componentRef: ComponentRef) => {
            componentRef.dispose();
            return componentRef;
        });
    }
    this.component = this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(ModalComponent, this._elementRef, 'modalID');
}
```

**parent.html**

```
<!-- Modal -->
   <div #modalID></div>
 <div class="col-sm-12 btnpolicymargin">
                    <a (click)="getTerms()" data-remote="false" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTarget" class="tosModal">Terms and Conditions</a>   
                    <a (click)="getPolicy()" data-remote="false" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTarget" class="pcModal">Parent Consent Policy</a> 
                </div>
```

**parentcomponent.ts** - below piece of code in parent component

```
getTerms() {
    this._modalService.setModalId('T&C');
    this.instantiateModalComponent();
}
getPolicy() {
    this._modalService.setModalId('ParentPolicy');
    this.instantiateModalComponent();
}
instantiateModalComponent() {
    if (this.component !== undefined) {
        this.component.then((componentRef: ComponentRef) => {
            componentRef.dispose();
            return componentRef;
        });
    }
    this.component = this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(ModalComponent, this._elementRef, 'modalID');
}
```

**Modal template**

```
 <div id="modalTarget" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content -->
       <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h4>
             </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div [innerHTML]="modalData"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

**ModalComponent**

```
constructor(private _modalService:ModalService) {
  this._modalService.updateModalId.subscribe(modalId => {
      this.modalID = modalId;
      console.log('id:' + this.modalID);
      switch (this.modalID) {
          case 'FAQ':
              this.goFAQ();
              break;
          case 'T&C':
               this.getTerms();
               break;
          case 'ParentPolicy':
               this.getPolicy();
               break;
          default:
              break;
      }
  });
  }
  goFAQ() {
    this._modalService.goFAQ().subscribe(data => {
        this.modalData = data;
        this.modalTitle = 'Frequently Asked Questions';
    });
}
```

Modal service is used to set modalId which indicates which button is pressed. Also when setting an event emitter is used to pass data to other components.

Can somebody help me to understand what could be the issue? why modal component getting instantiated more number of times and calling backend more than needed.?is it because modal is getting used by 2 different components?

Comment: Can you create a Plunker? Your code is missing essentials parts like `@Component()` decorators. Hard to see what's going on

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - I am sorry. I pasted only things which is relevant of the issue. All essential parts like @Component() are in place. Actually whatever code placed inside subscribe of Modal - (this._modalService.updateModalId.subscribe) of Modal Component is executed more num of times. You can see that in header.html and parent.html how i have used #modalID. If i change <modal-component> to div, the modal data will become undefined. :(

Comment: When i remove dynamic component loader, there is no repetition. For my scenario, I guess I wrongly interpreted and used dynamic component loader. Anyways without that its running as expected.